Solving a second-order recurrence relation / Series expansion of a confluent Heun equation
I would like to know whether it is possible to solve (in "closed form") either one of the following two second-order recurrence relations, which are closely related to each other. The first is
$$n(n-1)c_n-(n-1)^2c_{n-1}-\omega^2(c_{n-2}-c_{n-1})=0,$$
and the other is
$$n^2b_n-(n-1)^2b_{n-1}+\omega^2b_{n-2}=0,$$
where $\omega^2$ is an arbitrary real parameter.
Background:
These equations arise from the second-order linear ODE
$$F''(u)+\frac{F'(u)}{u-1}+\frac{\omega^2}{u}F(u)=0.\label{1}\tag{$*$}$$
This ODE is of confluent Heun type and admits the two linearly independent solutions
$$F_1(u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nu^n=u\ Hc(\omega^2-1,\omega^2,2,1,0,u),$$
and
$$F_2(u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(1-u)^n=Hc(0,-\omega^2,1,0,0,1-u),$$
where $Hc(q,\alpha,\gamma,\delta,\epsilon,z)$ denotes the confluent Heun function as implemented in Mathematica. That is, it is the solution to
$$
z(z-1)y''+[\gamma(z-1)+\delta z+z(z-1)\epsilon]y'+(\alpha z-q)y=,0
$$
which is normalized to one at $z=0$. These solutions may become linearly dependent for special discrete values of $\omega$.
"Closed form":
I am hoping to be able to find an "explicit" form of the series coefficients $b_n$ or $c_n$ in the expansion of the above Heun functions. I found an old paper by Harold Exton ("New Solutions of the Confluent Heun Equation", Le Matematiche (Catania) 53, No. 1, 11-20 (1998), MR1681613, Zbl 0929.34008) which is supposed to provide an explicit triple series representation of the confluent Heun function, but Exton's results appear to require $\epsilon\neq0$.
I realize the general Heun equation is complicated in general, but in this case many of the parameters are zero or take simple values, so I am hoping it may be possible to obtain a direct formula for $b_n$ or $c_n$ (possibly as a sum over many terms) that does not involve the preceding terms. Or if such a thing is not possible, that would also be great to know.
Thank you!
Edit: a new approach
By inspecting the equation, and in the great physics tradition of inventing a new expansion parameter when none is available, it seems fruitful to introduce a new coordinate $\rho$ and parameter $\Omega$ by letting
$$u=\Omega^2\rho^2,\quad\omega=\frac{\lambda}{2\Omega}.$$
With these rescalings, the original ODE $(*)$ becomes
$$F''(\rho)-\frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{1+\Omega^2\rho^2}{1-\Omega^2\rho^2}\right)F'(\rho)+\lambda^2F(\rho)=0,$$
and the first solution becomes
$$F_1(\rho)=\Omega^2\rho^2\ Hc\left(\frac{\lambda^2}{4\Omega^2}-1,\frac{\lambda^2}{4\Omega^2},2,1,0,\Omega^2\rho^2\right).$$
The advantage is that the ODE and its solutions can now be expanded in (inverse) powers of $\omega=2\Omega/\lambda$. Indeed, one can show that
$$F_1(\rho)=8\Omega\rho\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\Omega}{4\lambda}\right)^kf_k(\Omega\rho)J_k(\lambda\rho),$$
where the $J_k(x)$ are the Bessel functions of the first kind, and the functions $f_n(X)$ are recursively defined by
$$f_1(X)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-X^2}},$$
and
$$f_n(X)=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-X^2}}\times\int\left(\sqrt{1-X^2}f_{n-1}''(X)-\frac{2n\left(1-X^2\right)-3+5X^2}{X\sqrt{1-X^2}}f_{n-1}'(X)+\frac{(n-2)\left[n\left(1-X^2\right)+2X^2\right]}{X^2\sqrt{1-X^2}}f_{n-1}(X)\right)\mathrm{d}X.$$
In particular,
$$f_2(X)=\frac{\left(1-X^2\right)\mathrm{arctanh}(X)-X}{\left(1-X^2\right)^{3/2}},$$
$$f_3(X)=\frac{\left(1-X^2\right)
^2\mathrm{arctanh}^2(X)+\frac{12-14X^2}{X}\left(1-X^2\right)\mathrm{arctanh}(X)-3\left(4-7X^2\right)}{2\left(1-X^2\right)^{5/2}},\ldots$$
Does anyone know how to find a direct formula for $f_n(X)$ or the full sum $F_1(\rho)$?

As these are three-term recurrences, I suspect there will be two solutions — one dominant and one minimal. Do you need the minimal one? Also, the space of "initial conditions" $(b_0,b_1)$ or $(c_0,c_1)$ is two-dimensional, but from linearity we can divide out by an overall scale, so it's really just one-dimensional. So minimality is either a "shooting" problem for an initial condition, or a quantization condition on $\omega$.

I don't think I need the minimal one. At this point, I will take anything :)

@AlexLupsasca I think a factor $2\eta^2/\lambda$ is missing in the equation $F_1(x)=\ldots$ in the new approach.

@FredHucht, I made progress on the "new approach": as you can see, I was able to collect all the coefficients of each Bessel function together. The result looks messy but I'm still hoping there exists some closed-form expression for the full sum in terms of some elementary functions.

The denominators of $f_n(X)$ obey a simple pattern. As for the numerators, they are polynomials in $\mathrm{arctanh}(X)$ and the two highest powers have easy to determine coefficients, but I can't yet spot a pattern for the others.

This is not an answer, only some observations:
The denominators $d_n$ of $b_n$ are given by ($n=0,1,\ldots$)
\begin{align}
d_n &= \{1,1, 4, 9, 64, 900, 20736,\ldots\} \\
&\stackrel{n\neq1}{=} \frac{n!^2}{(n-1)^2}.
\end{align}
They can be removed from the sequence $b_n$ by defining a modified sequence
\begin{align}
b_0'&=1 \\
b_1'&=1 \\
b_{n}' &= n^2b_{n-1}' - \omega^2 (n-1)^2 b_{n-2}'\,,
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}
-\frac{n!^2}{\omega^2(n-1)^2} b_n=b_{n-2}'\, ,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
b_2' &= 4-\omega^2 \\
b_3' &= 36-13\omega^2 \\ 
b_4' &= 576-244\omega^2+9\omega^4 \\
&\ldots\,. 
\end{align}
Observe that the constant term in $b_n'$ is $n!^2$, while the coefficients of $\omega^2$ are given by A203156.
A similar transformation can be done with $c_n$: Define
\begin{align}
c_{-1}'&=1 \\
c_0'&=1 \\
c_{n}' &= (n^2+\omega^2)c_{n-1}' + \omega^2 n(n-1) c_{n-2}'
\end{align}
to get
\begin{align}
\frac{n!^2}{n} c_n=c_{n-1}'
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
c_1' &= 1-\omega^2 \\
c_2' &= 4-3\omega^2+\omega^4 \\
c_3' &= 36-25\omega^2+6\omega^4-\omega^6 \\ 
c_4' &= 576-388\omega^2+85\omega^4-10\omega^6+\omega^8 \\
&\ldots\,. 
\end{align}

Thank you for your comment, Fred. Using a very different approach from you, I also found the coefficients of ^2 in terms of the digamma function, but I was not able to obtain a formula for the coefficients of ^4.

I also found a new possible approach to the problem, which I added to my original question---perhaps you will have some insight into that new expansion. Thank you!

A methodology to find the corresponding formula for the coefficients of $\omega^{2n}$ from @FredHucht's response.
When we take $F_1(u)=\sum_{n\geq0}c_nu^n$ it follows that $c_0=0$, $c_1$ is our constant of integration, $c_2=\frac12 c_1$, and
\begin{align}
n(n-1)c_n+(\omega^2-(n-1)^2)c_{n-1}=\omega^2c_{n-2};\quad [n\geq3].
\end{align}
If we then take $c_n=nc_{n-1}'/n!^2$ it must follow that $c_{-1}'=0$, $c_0'=c_1$, and $c_1'=c_1$, but not $c_{-1}'=1$! So we are left with the relation
\begin{align}
c'_n=(n^2+\omega^2)c_{n-1}'+\omega^2n(n-1)c_{n-2}';\quad[n\geq2]
\end{align}
$c_1$ can be set to 1 without loss of generality, giving
\begin{align}
&c_0'=1\\
&c_1'=1\\
&c_2'=4+3\omega^2\\
&c_3'=36+37\omega^2+3\omega^4\\
&c_4'=576+676\omega^2+121\omega^4+3\omega^6\\
&\vdots
\end{align}
Now for something neat! Let $c_n'=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\kappa_{n,m}\omega^{2m}$, so
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\kappa_{n,m}\omega^{2m}=\sum_{m=0}^{n-2}n^2\kappa_{n-1,m}\omega^{2m}+\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\kappa_{n-1,m-1}\omega^{2m}+\sum_{m=1}^{n-2}n(n-1)\kappa_{n-2,m-1}\omega^{2m},
\end{align}
and so we have
\begin{align}
\kappa_{n,n}&=\kappa_{n-1,n-1},\qquad \kappa_{n,0}=n^2\kappa_{n-1,0},\\
\kappa_{n,m}&=n^2\kappa_{n-1,m}+\kappa_{n-1,m-1}+n(n-1)\kappa_{n-2,m-1};\quad n\geq4, m\in [1,n-2]
\end{align}
From the first two we recover $\kappa_{n,n-1}=3$ (for $n\geq2$) and $\kappa_{n,0}= n!^2$ (for $n\geq0$).
If we wish to find the coefficient of the second highest order term of $\omega^2$ we set $m=n-2$ to get
\begin{align}
\kappa_{n,n-2}=n^2\kappa_{n-1,n-2}+\kappa_{n-1,n-3}+n(n-1)\kappa_{n-2,n-3},\\
\kappa_{n,n-2}-\kappa_{n-1,n-3}=3n^2+3n(n-1)=3n(2n-1),\\
\sum_{k=4}^n(\kappa_{k,k-2}-\kappa_{k-1,k-3})=\sum_{k=4}^n 3k(2k-1),\\
\kappa_{n,n-2}=\frac12n(4n-1)(n+1)-29,\quad [n\geq3].
\end{align}
Similarly, we can find the coefficients $\kappa_{n,1}$: let $m=1$ to get
\begin{align}
\kappa_{n,1}=n^2\kappa_{n-1,1}+\kappa_{n,0}+n(n-1)\kappa_{n-2,0},\\
\kappa_{n,1}-n^2\kappa_{n-1,1}=(n-1)!^2+n(n-1)(n-2)!^2,\\\\
\frac{\kappa_{n,1}}{n!^2}-\frac{\kappa_{n-1,1}}{(n-1)!^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n(n-1)},\\\\
\sum_{k=3}^n\left(\frac{\kappa_{k,1}}{k!^2}-\frac{\kappa_{k-1,1}}{(k-1)!^2}\right)=\sum_{k=3}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k(k-1)}\right),\\\\
\kappa_{n,1}=n!^2\left(\frac34+\sum_{k=3}^n\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k(k-1)}\right)\right),\quad [n\geq3].
\end{align}
As far as a general formula for $\kappa_{n,m}$, I have been unable to find one, perhaps something involving induction might work? I imagine a similar method for $b_n'$ would work which I will leave as an exercise for the reader.

Thank you, Eli. This is a beautiful answer with encouraging progress! I will try to solve for a few more coefficients $\kappa_{n,m}$ and hopefully a pattern will emerge.

Based on your experience, do you think a general formula for $\kappa_{m,n}$ may exist?

@AlexLupsasca I don't know usually I don't even get that far haha

Let's forge ahead! Your formula for $\kappa_{n,1}$ evaluates to $(n!)^2\left(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\psi'(n)\right)$ where $\psi(z)=\Gamma'(z)/\Gamma(z)$ is the digamma function.

Mathematica cannot solve the recurrence relation for $\kappa_{n,2}$ in closed forn. On the other hand, it can solve the one for $\kappa_{n,n-3}$, returning $\kappa_{n,n-3}=c+\frac{1}{120}n(n+1)\left(658-2573n+343n^2-248n^3+80n^4\right)$.

The constant is $c=599$.

You can find a recursive solution for $\kappa_{n,m}$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\kappa_{n,m}=n!^2\left[c+\sum_{i=a}^n\left(\frac{\kappa_{i-1,m-1}}{i!^2}+\frac{i(i-1)\kappa_{i-2,m-1}}{i!^2}\right)\right],
\end{align}
for which I believe $a=3$ is correct but haven't verified, and $c$ is our initial value. The only problem I see is that we our creating more work for ourselves than just solving for $c_n'$ recursively!

Hmm, I don't see how to use this yet. But clearly, one can keep decreasing $m$. For instance, I just found $\kappa_{n,n-4}=\frac{1}{15120}n(n+1)\left(-1625580+6501612n-773813n^2+696470n^3-346085n^4+94988n^5-21392n^6+2240n^7\right)-21249$. And one can surely keep going! But these keep getting more complicated so this is only useful if a pattern emerges.

wait, there is a typo in your very first equation. You wrote $n(n-1)c_n+\left(\omega^2+(n-1)^2\right)c_{n -1}=\omega^2c_ {n-2}$ but it should be $n(n-1)c_n+\left(\omega^2-(n-1)^2\right)c_{n -1}=\omega^2c_ {n-2}$.
